# How to categorize or divide total days proportionately to a specific category using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say I have 65.52 days

And i want to divide this number into portion of 13.25 days so the output result would be like in cumulative

- 13.25 days
- 26.51 days
- 39.77 days
- 53.02 days
- 65.52 days

Notice the categorization is cumulative from the divided value for example second value 26.51 days = 13.25 + 13.25 and third is 39.77 = 26.51 days + 13.25 days

However at the end the value fall exactly at the limit of the total days. Not exceed and it is not +13.25 anymore.

```
Item    Total Days  Divided     Categorized
Roc-1   65.52       13.26           13.26
                    13.26           26.51
                    13.26           39.77
                    13.26           53.02
                    12.50           65.52
```

Comment: The dbms is mysql

Comment: Can you please post a specific input and output case, how does the table data look like?

Comment: see the edited detail something like that actually it is like categorizing them into certain portion but the last portion does not necessarily 13.26 because it must fall into the limit of the total days

Comment: I don't get this - for example second value 26.51 days = 13.25 + 13.25 is not true, 26.50 = 13.25 + 13.25 and 39.77  = 26.51 + 13.25 is not true, 39.77 = 26.51 + 13.26. Also why do you talk about 13.25 as the divided value in the text portion of the question and 13.26 in the table?

Comment: Actually simple 13.26 + 13.26 = 26.51 and then 26.51 + 13.26 = 39.77 and then 39.77 + 13.26 = 53.02 however at the end because the limit is 65.51 it cannot + 13.26 anymore it should plus 12.50 so that it made up exactly the total 65.51

Comment: 13.26 + 13.26 = 26.51?

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry for the tiny mistakes because of the rounding it should be 26.52...all though there is more decimal at the back

Answer (score 0):

Since roc-1 is mentioned in the question the split may have a relationship with the number of entries in a table for roc-1 so this might work

```
select t1.*,
        @rn:=@rn+1 rn,
        @maxrows maxrows,
        cast(
        case 
            when @rn <> @maxrows then @divided
            else 65.52 - (@divided * (@rn -1))
        end 
        as decimal(5,2))
         divided
        ,cast(
        case 
            when @rn <> @maxrows then   @cum_total:= @cum_total + @divided
            else @cum_total:=@cum_total + 65.52 - (@divided * (@rn -1))
         end 
         as decimal(5,2))
         cumtot

from  (select @divided:= 13.26,@cum_total:=0) d,
        (select @rn:=0) rn,
        (select @maxrows:= (select count(*) from table1 t where t.id = 'roc-1')) maxrows,
        table1 t1

+-------+------+---------+---------+--------+
| ID    | rn   | maxrows | divided | cumtot |
+-------+------+---------+---------+--------+
| roc-1 |    1 |       5 |   13.26 |  13.26 |
| roc-1 |    2 |       5 |   13.26 |  26.52 |
| roc-1 |    3 |       5 |   13.26 |  39.78 |
| roc-1 |    4 |       5 |   13.26 |  53.04 |
| roc-1 |    5 |       5 |   12.48 |  65.52 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+--------+
```